# MySQL query browser - run more statements in one query

Tags: mysql

How to run more statements in one query? E.g.

```
-- TABLE users --
CREATE TABLE  `DTB`.`table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE  `DTB`.`table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250

INSERT INTO `DTB`.`table1` VALUES 
...

INSERT INTO `DTB`.`table2` VALUES
...
```

I'm able to run each statements separately and it works, but I'm not able to create one sql script which creates whole database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate each query by `;`

So this will not work:

```
insert into foo values(10)
insert into bar values('test')
insert into test values(42)
```

but this will:

```
insert into foo values(10);
insert into bar values('test');
insert into test values(42);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried it, but It doesn't work: `You have an error in your SQL syntax, check manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near';`

Comment: You most probably have an error in one of your queries. Clear the screen and execute this: `select 1; select 2;`. It should work.

Comment: Each of them are working fine separately. But when i try to run `select1; select2;` in one query, it fails on `;` :-/

Comment: I'm not using MySQL query browser but there should be a pane where you can load an sql script or manually type in many queries (separated by `;`) and run them.

Comment: Also note that in the example I gave you there is a space between `select` and `1`. The same holds for the second query.

Comment: Aha, you're right. I have to open a new script, not query. It works. Thanky cherouvim :)